# Replace cout<<"string" with cout<<"string"<<endl in cpp

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I want to replace each `cout` occurring in a program with same but *concatenated with `endl`*. I'm trying to use macros for this but unable to figure that out how to do that. Please help!

Is there a way to get complete line written in program and just concat `<< endl` with it?
Note if `endl` is already written by programmer, no `endl` will be concatenated.

If any other better method possible, please suggest.

Comment: Simply attach a newline `\n` to the strings you output, i.e. instead of `cout << "blah";` write `cout << "blah\n";`. In most cases, the newline is enough and you don't need to explicitly flush the buffer. Using macros simply to save a few characters is a bad idea here and will come back to bite you later.

Comment: Is the first cout in the question supposed to be capitalized? Also is this a one-time fix, or is it supposed to run with every build.

Comment: i want this not to explicitly write endl again and again, cpp preprocessor should do this for me.

Comment: This is what Replace All is for.  Could likely search for `";` with a replace to `" << endl;`  It's boring grunt work if its on a large base, but your co-workers won't hang you out a window afterwards.

Comment: What you're trying to do is beyond the capabilities of macros.

Comment: nops, sorry  by mistake it was caps.. i just want to concat endl to every cout written in program, if not explicitly specified.

Comment: if you have to fix already written code, then robust ways should be aware of the C++ syntax; simpler and less robust ways can just search for the `;` in a statement beginning with `cout` (or `std::count`?), and replace `;` with `<<endl;` or `<<std::endl;`. I suspect Cpp can't help you alone; if it is to save keystrokes, is it really too much a waste of time to add `<<endl;`? With a smart editor, you can configure a shortcut…

Comment: I am trying to make preprocessor should do task for me and replace all my couts in any of the .cpp or .h for which im going to use that code. I dont wanna use replace or replace all.

Comment: The preprocessor isn't powerful enough to do this. You'll have to do something else.

Comment: *If any other better method possible, please suggest.* It seems you're not interested in other methods though. Why are you so hellbent on using the preprocessor to solve this problem?

Comment: I already said, if something other can do this trick, you may suggest the one better than this. again i dont want ide to do that as people are saying to use replaceall or regular exp i want if prg writes cout<<y; and compiles in obj automatically cout<<y<<endl should go.

Comment: Are You using Visual Studio? Then you have "find and replace" tool that also accepts regular expressions. It should piece of cake then.

Comment: @tomi.lee.jones dude you are not judging the right need of this. i dont want find and replace. i want an automatic behaviour when code is preprocessed or optimised. please read earlier comment

Comment: @rohit its fine, they weren't posted when i started to write this. I guess others has answered You already then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is possible.  But in no sense can I condone it.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace std
{
class not_actually_cout{};

template<typename T>
not_actually_cout& operator<< (not_actually_cout& stream, const T & v)
{
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
    return stream;
}

not_actually_cout not_actually_cout_instance;
}

#define cout not_actually_cout_instance

int main(void)
{
    cout << "why god why";
    cout << "please no";
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
why god why
please no
```

Comment: Note that this code is **not** portable: you are not allowed to `#define` any of the standard C++ library identifiers.

Comment: This will insert a newline for every `<<` operation.  e.g. `cout << 1 << 2;` will put a newline after 1 and after 2.  Is that what's desired? The wording of the question implies to me that it is not.

Comment: @SamCristall The International Court of Justice in The Hague has been notified about your answer---a crime against humanity.

Answer (score 9):

Just make a function template:

```
template<typename T>
void printLn(T const & v, std::ostream & os = std::cout)
{
    os << v << std::endl;
}
```

If you wanna get fancy with it and allow multiple arguments, and C++11 is available to you:

```
void printLn(std::ostream & os)
{
    os << std::endl;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void printLn(std::ostream & os, T const & v, Args&&... args)
{
    os << v;
    printLn(os, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how this helps with *I want to replace `std::cout << "blah";` with `std::cout << "blah" << std::endl;`* The OP will still have to find all instances and replace them with `printLn(...)`

Comment: @Praetorian: I'm basing my answer off of this comment: *"i want this not to explicitly write endl again and again"* -- The idea is to get rid of the tedium of appending `<< std::endl` when you want to end a line.  I also doubt the OP *really* will be pleased with the thing he is requesting, and I interpreted it as an XY problem.

Comment: OK, I totally misunderstood the question. I read it as *I have all these `cout` statements that I must append newline and flush, how do I do that?*

Answer (score 1):

What are you really interested in? The newline after each output operation or the flush? Note that the flush is really expensive, though.

The easiest way to have a flush injected after each output operation is to set the flags `std::ios_base::unitbuf` (this is the default setting for `std::cerr`):

```
std::cout << std::unitbuf;
```

After this operation, you'll get a flush after each individual output operation, e.g.

```
std::cout << "hello" << ' ' << "world\n";
```

would cause three flushes. To automatically also insert a newline, you could set up a filtering stream buffer which adds a newline (optionally if there wasn't one) upon flushing the stream. This would amount to overwriting the `overflow()` and `sync()` functions of a `std::streambuf` and installing the corresponding stream buffer into `std::cout` in addition to setting `std::unitbuf`. With these changes, no source change would be needed.

The code below demonstrates a corresponding filtering stream buffer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <streambuf>

class newlinebuf
    : public std::streambuf
{
    enum { s_size = 64 };
    std::ostream&   d_stream;
    std::streambuf* d_sbuf;
    char            d_buffer[s_size];
public:
    newlinebuf(std::ostream& stream)
        : d_stream(stream)
        , d_sbuf(stream.rdbuf(this))
    {
        this->setp(this->d_buffer, this->d_buffer + s_size - 1);
    }
    ~newlinebuf() {
        if (this->d_stream.rdbuf() == this) {
            this->d_stream.rdbuf(this->d_sbuf);
        }
    }
    int overflow(int c) { // clear the buffer without flushing
        std::streamsize size(this->pptr() - this->pbase());
        std::streamsize n(this->d_sbuf->sputn(this->pbase(), size));
        if (n == 0) { // no progress => error
            return std::char_traits<char>::eof();
        }
        std::copy(this->pbase() + n, this->pbase() + size, this->pbase());
        this->setp(this->d_buffer, this->d_buffer + s_size);
        this->pbump(size - n);
        if (c != std::char_traits<char>::eof()) {
            *this->pptr() = std::char_traits<char>::to_char_type(c);
            this->pbump(1);
        }
        return std::char_traits<char>::not_eof(c);
    }
    int sync() {
        if (this->pptr() == this->pbase() || this->pptr()[-1] != '\n') {
            *this->pptr() = '\n';
            this->pbump(1);
        }
        return this->overflow(std::char_traits<char>::eof())
            == std::char_traits<char>::eof()? -1: 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
    newlinebuf sbuf(std::cout << std::unitbuf);

    std::cout << "hello" << "_" << "world\n" << "next line";
}
```

Based on the comment I realize that this is probably not what you want but I'm not aware of a portable technique which just uses the preprocessor and/or the compiler to add newlines.

Comment: i just want a linefeed nd that too by compiler or preprocessor.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use regular expressions. All modern languages has support for them.

Also, for example, if your program not so big, you can try to use SublimeText editor. It has very smart tools for replacement, which supports regex.

Comment: Thanks Sir, but is there any built in support, i dont wanna use third party library.

Comment: He's not suggesting you do this at runtime, just use your editor to change the text.  Every major IDE has RegEx support to replace text.

Comment: @SamCristall I guess you took me wrong, i want code should change to cout<<blah<<endl; when i compile my code. This is dynamic and i dont want programmer to write endl endl after every cout.